# How do I interpret hang / CPU usage diagnostic files for macOS? Documentation?

Tags: macos, freeze

If my Mac app hangs, it generates diagnostic files that end in `.hang` or `.cpu_resource.diag`. They look somewhat like crash reports, but with deep tab-indented hierarchies of what looks like process samples.

Example:

```
Powerstats for:  MyApp [13095] thread 0x9b152
UUID:            35BE255F-F3B3-3188-B1E4-12E96CAAD397
Start time:      2020-09-26 15:37:35 -0500
End time:        2020-09-26 15:39:03 -0500
Parent:          launchd
Microstackshots: 55 samples (47%)
Primary state:   52 samples Frontmost App, User mode, Thread QoS User Interactive
User Activity:   0 samples Idle, 55 samples Active
Power Source:    0 samples on Battery, 55 samples on AC
  55 start + 1 (libdyld.dylib) [0x7fff8bed55ad]
    55 main + 121 (MyApp) [0x108ee8d5f]
      55 NSApplicationMain + 1176 (AppKit) [0x7fff8ffed368]
        55 -[NSApplication run] + 682 (AppKit) [0x7fff90023d80]
          55 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454 (AppKit) [0x7fff9002f226]
            55 _DPSNextEvent + 1067 (AppKit) [0x7fff9002fdf6]
              55 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff866e35af]
                55 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff866e3677]
                  55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox) [0x7fff866e3935]
                    55 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff973d5e48]
                      55 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff973f6f37]
                        55 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff973f6fc7]
                          55 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 71 (QuartzCore) [0x7fff99fcf863]
...and on and on, much deeper
```

How do I interpret these diagnostic files? Can someone link to some Apple documentation of them?